# PHP MYSQLi: Admin edit user level

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a users.php where admin can see all registered users information and he is able to change their levels with a form that goes to edit_level.php.

It's not working properly, when I change the level of a user, it is affecting the wrong user.

This is my form in users.php (I didn’t include all the user info , just the level part)

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY username ASC";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql) or die(mysqli_error());
    
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

$level = $row['level'];

<form method='post' action='edit_level.php?ed=$id'>
    <input type='hidden' name='id' value='$row[id]'>
    <input type='text' name='level' value='$row[level]'>
    <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Change Level'>
}
```

This is edit_level.php

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    
    $ed_id = $_GET['ed'];
    $level = $_POST['level'];
    $sql = "UPDATE users SET level ='$level' WHERE id='$ed_id'";
    
    if(mysqli_query($conn,$sql)){
    echo "<p>User Level has been sucessfully udpated! <a href='users.php'>Click here to return to User List.</a>";
    }
    else{
        echo "<p><b>ERROR:User level has not been updated!";
    }   
}
```

Edit:

I actually just copied the same format of a delete function I have, but the delete was a link not a form.

```
<a href='deleteaccount.php?del=$id'>Delete</a> and then in the php: 

$del_id = $_GET['del']; 
$sql = "DELETE FROM users WHERE id='$del_id'";
```

Not sure how to do the same but with a form. I need a form because I want to be able to type a new value.

Comment: Your post form stores the id as "id" but your script reads "ed", is that the problem?

Comment: @Johnny : You have created form in while loop. So if there are 10 users then 10 forms will be created and all the hidden fields will have same name. This will not give you correct post values.

Comment: Yes for each user there is a Submit button next to it. How should I do it?

Comment: I had to use a form in a loop because I want to read the level from user table and be able to edit it and submit the changes. Not sure how to fix this.

Comment: You should create one form and call ajax to update

Comment: Hmm I'm not good with ajax

Comment: No other way to do it? Where should my form be placed?

Comment: You are editing a record according to this: `action='edit_level.php?ed=$id'`, where do you take the `$id` from?

Comment: I don't know, i actually just copied the same format of a delete function I have, but the delete was a link not a form. <a href='deleteaccount.php?del=$id'>Delete</a>  and then in the php: $del_id = $_GET['del']; $sql = "DELETE FROM users WHERE id='$del_id'"; Not sure how to do the same but with a form. I need a form cuz I want to be able to type a new value.

Comment: echo your post values on edit_level.php? What you're seeing?

Comment: I did echo $level = $_POST['level']; Im seeing Registered for everyone, even for Administrator. I have 2 possible values for level in user table, Registered and Adminsitrator, default is Registered. Here is the DB line-->`level` ENUM('Registered','Administrator') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Registered',

Comment: Check this http://postimg.org/image/tbt3ti331/, thats how my users.php look like

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is wrong naming. Below on `action` attribute you are sending `$id` value with `ed` name, but on hidden input you are sending `$id` value with `id` name.

If you are using `?ed=$id` on action why you are using `hidden $id`? Or if you are using `hidden $id` why you are using `?ed=$id` on action area.

```
<form method='post' action='edit_level.php?ed=$id'>
    <input type='hidden' name='id' value='$row[id]'>
```

You should remove `ed` or `id` then if your edit_level.php gets `$id` value by `$_GET` or `$_POST` you should fix it like below

**edit_level.php**

if you used hidden field you can get `$id` like `$_POST["id"]`
if you used edit_level.php?ed=$id you can get `$id` like `$_GET["ed"]`

Decide what you want. But don't forget to change you action page while you are doing these changes.

Comment: I am a bit confused by what you said, I don't really understand what changes to make.

Comment: when im clicking any button, im getting edit_level.php?ed=2 ed is always equal 2

Comment: another thing, the only changes that happen is when I change the value of username c and press submit, it changes the value of username a (usernames according to the picture)

Comment: Only the first row is getting updated, and its value only changes when the last row Submit button is pressed

Comment: Can anyone help please?